# Logstash sync mongo data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, synchronization, logstash

I'm newbie for using Logstash and Elasticsearch. I wanted to sync my MongoDB data into Elasticsearch using Logstash Plugin (logstash-input-mongodb).
In my mongodata.conf is

```
input {
uri => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/final?ssl=true'
placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
collection => 'twitter_stream'
batch_size => 5000
}
filter {

}
output {
stdout {
codec => rubydebug
}
elasticsearch {
action => "index"
index => "twitter_stream"
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
}
```

While I running **bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/mongodata.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash/**

The error was displayed like this

```
Sending Logstash logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-02-28T08:48:20,246][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-02-28T08:48:20,331][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.6.0"}
[2020-02-28T08:48:20,883][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#", "{" at line 2, column 13 (byte 21) after input {\n uri ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:47:in compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:55:in compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:17:in block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2580:in map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:14:in compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:161:in initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:27:in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:326:in block in converge_state'"]}
[2020-02-28T08:48:21,114][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-02-28T08:48:25,969][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.
```

Please help me, I don't have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong, you need to specify what type of `input` you are using.

Try to change your input to this one:

```
input {
  mongodb { 
     uri => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/final?ssl=true'
     placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
     placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
     collection => 'twitter_stream'
     batch_size => 5000
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I had change the code like above. It's work and there is I found another error. However, I think URI to connect mongodb was wrong. Where I can get the right URI to connect mongodb? Thankyou